# How to embed subtitles in multiple movies in an automated way using python?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, video-subtitles

This python script identifies all movies with mp4 extension and, if they have subtitles in srt format, converts the subtitle encoding to utf-8 (without this conversion you will get error message) and starts building the movie with the subtitle embedded.

```
for filename in glob.glob("*.mp4"):
    print(str(filename))
    if 'wsubs' not in filename:
        for legenda in glob.glob(filename.replace(".mp4",".srt")):
            try:
                with open(legenda, 'r') as arquivo_orig:
                    conteudo = arquivo_orig.read()
                with open(legenda, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as novo_arquivo:
                    novo_arquivo.write(conteudo)
            except Exception as e:
                print("Já codificado")
            print(str(legenda))
            os.system('ffmpeg -i "' + str(filename) + '" -vf subtitles="' + str(legenda) + '" -maxrate 2000000 -crf 20 "' + str(filename.replace('.mp4','-wsubs.mp4')) + '"')
```

The end result will be a subtitled movie with the expression "wsubs" at the end of the name. The original files will be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you are asking as it looks like you have answered your own question. So if it is an opinion on how to achieve what I think you are doing, this is how I would do it. *[I would have liked to have left this as a comment but my reputation is not high enough.]*

```
import os
import subprocess as sp


VIDEO_EXT = ".mp4"
SUBTITLE_EXT = ".srt"
SUB_TOKEN = "-wsubs"


def main(working_directory: str):
    for file in os.listdir(working_directory):
        full_name = os.path.join(working_directory, file)

        # Keep this statement in, but remove `main(full_name)` if you
        #   do not want to check all subdirectories.
        if os.path.isdir(full_name):
            main(full_name)
            continue

        file_base_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(file)
        sub_file = os.path.join(working_directory, file_base_name + SUBTITLE_EXT)
        result_file = os.path.join(working_directory, file_base_name + SUB_TOKEN + file_ext)

        # The video is already subbed.
        if os.path.exists(result_file):
            print(f"Video: {full_name} already has a subbed video.")
            continue

        if SUB_TOKEN not in file and VIDEO_EXT in file_ext and os.path.exists(sub_file):
            cmd = [
                "ffmpeg",
                "-v", "error",
                "-i", full_name,
                "-c:a", "copy",
                "-c:v", "libx264",
                "-x264-params", "nal-hrd=vbr",
                "-vf", "subtitles=pipe\\\\:0",
                "-crf", "20",
                "-maxrate", "2M",
                "-f", "mp4",
                result_file,
                "-y"
            ]

            # Pass the file handler to the subprocess directly
            with open(sub_file, "r") as f_:
                with sp.Popen(cmd, stdin=f_, stderr=sp.PIPE) as proc:
                    outs, err = proc.communicate()

            if proc.returncode != 0 and err:
                try:
                    os.remove(result_file)
                except OSError:
                    pass
                print("ffmpeg ran into an error: " + err.decode("UTF-8"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "files"))
```

The primary difference between the scripts is that I use subprocess to execute the ffmpeg command. I also pass the subtitles file though a pipe as with my experience; ffmpeg does not like certain filenames within the -vf argument. While not an important difference; I also use the os library to handle my filename manipulations.